# Efficient/optimized query for my query using multiple UNIONS with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

Can someone please have a look into query and suggest any improvement or optimized query for the same so that query runs faster .

So basically, I have 2 table Survey and SurveyInvite.

Sample data for Table **Survey**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Survey
(
  createdate   date, 
  emailinvite  char(4),
  phoneinvite  char(4),
  smsinvite    char(4),
  surveyid     int
);

INSERT dbo.Survey VALUES
('20220201','12ab','12bc', null ,1),
('20220210','23be','45hg','45tr',2),
('20220220','65hg', null ,'89kj',3);
```

Sample data for Table **SurveyInvite**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SurveyInvite
(
  sentdate date,
  id       char(4)
);

INSERT dbo.SurveyInvite VALUES
('20220201','12ab'),
('20220205','12bc'),
('20220210','23be'),
('20220214','45hg'),
('20220218','45tr'),
('20220220','65hg'),
('20220224','89kj');
```

The output should be

| Type | sentdate | inviteid | surveyid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Email | 2022-02-01 | 12ab | 1 |
| Email | 2022-02-10 | 23be | 2 |
| Email | 2022-02-20 | 65hg | 3 |
| Phone | 2022-02-05 | 12bc | 1 |
| Phone | 2022-02-14 | 45hg | 2 |
| SMS | 2022-02-18 | 45tr | 2 |
| SMS | 2022-02-24 | 89kj | 3 |

So basically, I have to get sentdate from SurveyInvite table against each type(email,phone,sms).

Survey table should be unpivoted on email,phone and sms to transform column into rows.

Here's my query

```sql
SELECT 'Email' as Type,esi.sentdate,emailinvite as inviteid,s.surveyid
FROM Survey s
INNER JOIN SurveyInvite esi on s.emailinvite=esi.id

UNION 

SELECT 'SMS' as Type,ssi.sentdate,smsinvite as inviteid,s.surveyid
FROM Survey s
INNER JOIN SurveyInvite ssi on s.smsinvite=ssi.id

UNION 

SELECT 'Phone' as Type,psi.sentdate,phoneinvite as inviteid,s.surveyid
FROM Survey s
INNER JOIN SurveyInvite psi on s.phoneinvite=psi.id
```

Please suggest other way to write query if that makes query faster. I am still trying using UNPIVOT,left join,CTE to avoid using UNION.

[Sample setup here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=092646dc173c91bd24d3a5753de0ae77)

Comment: `UNION ALL` can be faster than `UNION`, because `UNION` does the necessary work to deduplicate the result set.  Other than that, `UNION ALL` is the correct way to generate your result set. It's possible that indexes might help. To help you with that we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query the tables three times, you can just unpivot. The easiest way to do this is with a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  v.Type,
  ssi.sentdate,
  v.inviteid,
  s.surveyid
FROM Survey s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
  ('Email', s.emailinvite),
  ('Phone', s.phoneinvite),
  ('SMS',   s.smsinvite)
) v (Type, inviteid)
INNER JOIN SurveyInvite ssi on v.inviteid = ssi.id;
```

I suggest you consider normalizing your database in the first place by storing the data unpivoted in a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (again the key is to only read either table once instead of three times):

```
SELECT i.sentdate, 
       [Type] = REPLACE(u.Types, 'invite', ''),
       inviteid = u.id,
       u.surveyid
FROM dbo.Survey AS s
UNPIVOT (Id FOR Types IN 
  (emailinvite, phoneinvite, smsinvite)) AS u
INNER JOIN dbo.SurveyInvite AS i ON u.Id = i.id;
```

As you can see from the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de349c1b14238e8e8e3a5ce7bb8c5b57), this eliminates 4 of the 6 table scans and also an expensive distinct sort.

Comment: Thanks very much for quick response and guidance .
I am very clear now how to optimize my original query. 
Much Appreciated everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have set the primary and foreign keys correctly. It might also beneficial to have indexes on the foreign keys. See: [Should every SQL Server foreign key have a matching index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3650690/880990).

As always with these performance questions. Only benchmarking different variants can tell you which one is the fastest. The same query can perform very differently with a different set of data.

One possibility is to use joins and base the query on `SurveyInvite`:

```sql
SELECT
    I.sentdate,
    CASE WHEN SE.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Email'
         WHEN SP.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Phone'
         ELSE 'SMS'
    END AS Type,
    I.id AS inviteid,
    CASE WHEN SE.id IS NOT NULL THEN SE.surveyid
         WHEN SP.id IS NOT NULL THEN SP.surveyid
         ELSE SS.surveyid
    END AS surveyid
FROM
    SurveyInvite I
    LEFT JOIN Survey SE
        ON I.emailinvite = SE.id
    LEFT JOIN Survey SP
        ON I.phoneinvite = SP.id
    LEFT JOIN Survey SS
        ON I.smsinvite = SS.id
```